# Figure out with fopen

Tags: disassembly, x86, c++

Can anyone explain, why fopen takes as argument- not a file name- according to code takes some off_6A5D8C:

```
.text:00537F9F                 push    offset stru_6C4E40 ; FILE *
.text:00537FA4                 call    _fclose
.text:00537FA9                 push    offset aWt      ; "wt"
.text:00537FAE                 push    offset off_6A5D8C ; char *
.text:00537FB3                 call    _fopen
.text:00537FB8                 mov     dword_83AE9C, eax
```

and I tracked this off_6A5D8C it's pointed to label loc_4C554E:

```
.data:006A5D8C ; char off_6A5D8C
.data:006A5D8C off_6A5D8C      dd offset loc_4C554E    
.data:006A5D90 ; char aWt[]
.data:006A5D90 aWt             db 'wt',0
```

```
.text:004C554E loc_4C554E:
.text:004C554E                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:004C5550                 pop     ebp
.text:004C5551                 retn    0Ch
```

I am not expert in disassembling, may be it requires perform Undefine operation for loc_4C554E - and in this case it's looks like:

```
.text:004C554E unk_4C554E      db  8Bh ; Ë             ; DATA XREF: .data:off_6A5D8Co
.text:004C554F                 db 0E5h ; õ
.text:004C5550                 db  5Dh ; ]
.text:004C5551                 db 0C2h ; T
.text:004C5552                 db  0Ch
.text:004C5553                 db    0
```

Seems it is string terminated with 0. How to turn this string (file name) to readable look?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the difference between "NUL" vs 0x004C554E? It's probably helpful for future questions to include the raw bytes in your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes the file name, but IDA doesn't recognise it.

In this example, IDA interpreted `4`-byte string `NUL\x00` (`4E 55 4C 00`) as an offset (address `0x004C554E`) in the code. You may force it to interpret it as an ascii string simple by pressing <kbd>a</kbd> when the cursor is on the line `006A5D8C`.

The reason that the byte order is reversed is that `x86` architecture uses [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte ordering, so in case you interpret `4E 55 4C 00` as a number, the byte order will be reversed (hence `0x004C554E`).